# Moment.js to elegantly and efficiently get start of a two week period based on a date

Tags: javascript, performance, momentjs

I need to calculate the start of a pay period based on a given date. The pay period is Wednesday through two weeks later's Tuesday. So, given one pay period start date (a), and an another date (b), I need to calculate the start of the pay period (c).

I am using Moment.js to deal with dates and timezones, so the natural course of action would be to use it for this too.

I could do something like:

```
import 'moment' from 'moment-timezone'

const tzString = 'America/New_York' 
const oneStartOfPayPeriod = '1/25/2017'
const dateFormatString = 'M/DD/YYYY'

let a = moment(oneStartOfPayPeriod).tz(tzString)
let b1 = moment('1/26/2017', dateFormatString).tz(tzString)
let b2 = moment('11/23/1999', dateForamtString).tz(tzString)

const getDaysPastPayPeriod = b => Math.abs(
    b.startOf('day')
    .diff(
        a.startOf('day'),
        'days'
    ) % 14) 

const getStartOfPayPeriod = b => b.subtract(getDaysPastPayPeriod(b), 'days')

let [c1, c2] = [getStartOfPayPeriod(b1), getStartOfPayPeriod(b2)]
```

which I didn't test yet, because I wrote it as I was writing this question :)

I am wondering:

1. Is it efficient? (it will need to be transpiled and run in browsers, desktop and mobile)
2. Is there a more elegant solution? (I don't really like the getDaysPastPayPeriod function)

(although It is better than I thought it would turn out before I started writing this question)

Comment: Do not use moment string parser without argument with string not in ISO 8601 format (see [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/)), use [`moment(String, String);`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) instead, in your case: `moment('1/26/2017', 'M/DD/YYYY')`

Comment: thanks for the info, I will edit my question.